# How to compute next expectation?

Tags: probability, complex-analysis

$x$ and $y$ are normal random variables, $x\in N(\mu_x, \sigma_x^2), y\in N(\mu_y, \sigma_y^2)$ How to compute next expression $$ \mathbb{E} \arg (e^{ix} + e^{iy}) $$
In English, what is expected value of argument of complex random variable $e^{ix} + e^{iy}$?

EDIT:
Okay, in the comment thread there is next solution:
$$e^{ix} + e^{iy} = cos(x) + cos(y) + i[sin(x) + sin(y)]$$
$$\arg e^{ix} + e^{iy} = tan^{-1} \frac{sin(x) +sin(y)}{cos(x) + cos(y)}=tan^{-1}tan((x+y)/2) = (x + y)/2$$

How to compute argument for arbitrary number of random variables, $\arg e^{ix_1} + \dots  + e^{ix_N}$?

Comment: Are x and y independent?

Comment: yes, x and y are independent

Comment: Hint: Please simplify the argument of $e^{ix}+e^{iy}$. You will be surprised at how simple it turns out to be!

Comment: Still hard. Can do you do argument for 1 of them?

Comment: @KartikAudhkhasi erm how? Notice it is addition, not multiplication... Moreover, even if it is multiplication, this thing is 2\pi periodic, it is not just x+y...

Comment: To simplify the argument of $e^{ix}+e^{iy}$, use Euler's identity and then the definition of argument of a complex number. Trigonometric sum-product identities will be useful.

Comment: @KartikAudhkhasi i am not convinced at all, sorry.

Comment: Let me try: $e^{ix}+e^{iy} = cos(x)+cos(y)+i(sin(x)+sin(y))$. The argument of this complex number is $\tan^{-1}\frac{sin(x)+sin(y)}{cos(x)+cos(y)}$. Then you use the trigonometric sum-product identities to simplify. Please let me know in case there is any issue with these steps.

Comment: @KartikAudhkhasi Why do not you write an answer?

Comment: @KartikAudhkhasi indeed you get to a simple expression, but you have to deal with the periodicity of the arg in a arbitrary way.

Comment: @ashim [Sum prod identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities)

Comment: Yes, periodicity means you will get a family of solutions. However, we can also restrict to the principal value of the argument.

Comment: @user117318 then we get $tan^{-1}[tan((x+y)/2)tan((x-y)/2)]$ . It does not simplify life.

Comment: @ashim: I think the hints in this thread are more than enough. Please try solving yourself using these hints and then let us know the current status of your solution.

Comment: @ashim, try again, you should get $tan^{-1} tan(\frac {x+y}{2})$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @KartikAudhkhasi please look at updated question